# While loop for code below with user input

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, boto3, amazon-sqs

Would like to have a piecie of code where i'm asking for queue name and then create new sqs queue with name provided. If queue name alredy exists would like to have prompot looped for new name

```py
import boto3

sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
all_queues = sqs.queues.all()


while True:
    sqs_queue_name = input("Enter queue name: ")
    for queue in all_queues:
        if queue.attributes['QueueArn'].split(":")[-1] == sqs_queue_name:
            print(f"Queue {sqs_queue_name} already exists")
            continue
        else:
            queue = sqs.create_queue(QueueName=sqs_queue_name, Attributes={'DelaySeconds':'5'})
            print(queue.url)
            print(queue.attributes.get('DelaySeconds'))
```

What I'm doing wrong ? Code keep asking me for queue name so something wrong with while loop, can't see whats wrong with it...

Comment: What's going wrong that you want help with? Please edit to show the error you are having.

Comment: Code keep asking me for queue name so something wrong with while loop, can't see whats wrong with it...

Comment: You never break out of the while True: loop so you will always come back to the input. Also do you need to go through the whole for loop after you have one valid queue? Needs some restructuring here.

Comment: Could you please share that restructurisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that call all_queues = sqs.queues.all() returns a list,

I would condition breaking out of the while True: loop on having made a new queue.

I'd also eliminate that inner for loop.  Instead I'd make a list of queue names, and then check if the queue name I select is in that list. If it is I need to keep asking the user for a new queue name. If not, make the new queue and break out of the loop.

Something like this:

```
import boto3

sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
all_queues = sqs.queues.all()
queue_names = [x.attributes['QueueArn'].split(":")[-1] for x in all_queues]
while True:
    sqs_queue_name = input("Enter queue name: ")
    if sqs_queue_name in queue_names:
        print(f"Queue {sqs_queue_name} already exists")
        continue
    else:
        queue = sqs.create_queue(QueueName=sqs_queue_name, Attributes=   {'DelaySeconds':'5'})
        print(queue.url)
        print(queue.attributes.get('DelaySeconds'))
        break
```

Comment: List comprehension ! Damn need lots of practise - thank you